# D3 tree/cluster diagram - changing node text color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, colors, label

I would like to have diagram similar to this one: (the most important part is that I would like to have node text displayed in several colors; it doesn't matter whether the diagram is tree or cluster)

[image]

This is a test example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjhudd3w/1/)

[image]

I tried changing text color via `CSS`, and within `JavaScript` code, bit it always remains black. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
    fill: #5555ff;
```

in CSS for node/text solves the problem.

SVG text element does not care about `color` attribute, like other HTML elements. Setting `fill` is the right way.

[image]